# Where should I put my C++ program to run at startup?

Tags: boot, startup, c++

I am trying my Ubuntu-Server launches my program after boot, so I put my program's executable file address on `/etc/rc.local` followed by `space+&` like this:

```
/home/m/myapp &
```

But it didn't work!
My program is a simple C++ code that uses gtk+ library to show an image and it works when I run it manually. But I want it runs automatically at the startup, but don't know how?

EDIT: I want to make a simple purpose computer. Actually it's a robot that it's program is written in C++ and it's executable is on `/home/m/myapp`. Also I do not like to have login page. There is no user menu or ability to controll the system. So it must run after boot automatically.

If I want to explain more, the system should exactly work like this:

> When user turns on the system, it shows a welcome picture, then it
>   waits until the user says a voice command. then it recognizes the
>   voice, shows an image/video related to the voice, then shows the
>   welcome picture again and waits for new command.
>
> There is no menu, no
>   login page and nothing for user. this system only works by user
>   command as I said above!

So as I am new to Linux, I don't know is it a background program or not? And how can I do this?

Comment: Do you want it to start when you log in, or as a service in the background when the system boots? If you want it to start when you log in, it depends on which windowmanager you use.

Comment: @Alexander: I want to build a robot that uses Linux. So I think it should be something in background that executes without need to login.

Comment: probably should be changing the login manager to one that doesn't require login, eg "nodm"

Comment: @Jasen: what's the difference between login manager and background service?

Comment: Why you do not open my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GTK requires X, without X your program cannot display an image.

if you want it to run in the context of the login manager add it to the login manager's desktop environment. (this was /var/lib/something last time I looked at ubuntu)

else you can replace the login manager with a non-interactive one like 'nodm', which will open toyr session automatically and then just add your c++ app to your session's startup applications.

I'm not sure where you add applications to autostart in openbox, but `~/.xsession` always works.

create a `~/.xsession` file that does `yourapp&` and then `openbox-session` (see the man page for `xinit`)

Comment: Thanks Jason. As I said in my question, I can run my program manually, as I installed `xorg, xserver-xorg-video-fbdev and openbox` on my OS. I edited my post, maybe it can clear it more!