# My ubuntu-server doesn't execute my gtk-based program at startup!

Tags: boot, x-server, c++, rc, xinit

I have Ubuntu-server 16.04. Installed gtk3 and can execute my program manually by this command: `./img` when I go to it's directory `/home/m`.
[image]

But when I tried to add this line to my `/etc/rc.local` file:

```
/home/m/img &
```

It didn't work. This is my `rc.local` full content:

```
startx
/home/m/img &
exit 0
```

Then I tried to create `~/.xinitrc` file with this content:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash
/home/m/img &
exec openbox-session
```

Then made it executable by this command:
 `chmod +x ~/.xinitrc`

But I got nothing(even it didn't show my openbox after reboot), So I executed this command too:

```
ln -s ~/.xinitrc ~/.xsession
```

After that my openbox came back but my program didn't start after boot! or any other time!

> My goal is this: when I turned on my board, after boot, it runs my
>   gtk-based program and shows my image. It's something like Kiosk but a
>   c++ program should only show an image!

How should I do that?

EDIT: I did add this line:
 `/home/m/img &`
to my `/etc/xdg/openbox/autostart` file, and it works after login but doesn't show my image, it shows only a file icon at center of the screen. But when I go to this address `/home/m/` and run this command `./img` it shows my image in full screen!

Why this happens?

**Also I like to hide my mouse pointer and my windows borders but don't know how?

EDIT2: This is what I see after boot:
[image]

And this is what I see after trying this command(in write buttom corner an icon appears): `/home/m/img &`
[image]

Comment: That seems a very strange `rc.local`. Did you add the `startx` or is that an Ubuntu surprise?

Comment: @roaima, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402780/ and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401884/ for how people here have told the questioner to do this.

Comment: @JdeBP that's really helpful. The context also suggests that the OP's first sentence is wrong - and (in this case) actually misleading.

Comment: When you run `/home/m/img &` on a terminal, does your application work?

Comment: @Zip: No, it shows an icon in bottom right of the page...it's a window that I can extent it and there is that icon in center of that. I put 2 new pics in my post.

Comment: You need to either make your application work even on background (the & does that) or make your startup scripts run your application in a way it'll work, like without the `&`. You **can** make your app run without hanging the terminal by itself...

Comment: @Zip: I want to hide the mouse pointer and windows borders. And don't want any other programs run after my program. this is a single purpose computer. So which method is better you think?

Comment: You can probably obtain more useful answers if you state in the question what the contents of your `/home/m` directory are.  My educated guess is that that will make it blatantly obvious to answerers why there's no image if the program is run with a different working directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Also I like to hide my mouse pointer and my windows borders but don't know how?

You can append `-- -nocursor` to your `startx` to hide mouse pointer:

```
exec startx -- -nocursor
```

There are files `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml` and `/etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml` for you to edit (ref: http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Configuration) , e.g. (bottom in that files):

```
    ...
  </menu>
    <applications>

    <application class="*">
        <decor>no</decor>
        <position force="yes">
              <x>50</x>
              <y>50</y>
              <monitor>1</monitor>
        </position>
        <size>
              <width>300</width>
              <height>300</height>
        </size>
        <focus>yes</focus>
        <desktop>1</desktop>
        <layer>normal</layer>
        <iconic>no</iconic>
        <skip_pager>no</skip_pager>
        <skip_taskbar>no</skip_taskbar>
        <fullscreen>no</fullscreen>
        <maximized>false</maximized>
    </application>

</applications>
</openbox_config>
```

In which `<decor>no</decor>` above will make the image app become borderless. Adjust the `<width>` and `<height>` if you found your image doesn't show the complete size. You can also adjust `<x>`, `<y>` of the app.

There are more, e.g. comment out the menu tags (there are multiple `<context` tags has this `<menu>` entry):

```
  <mousebind button="Right" action="Press">
    <action name="ShowMenu">
        <!-- menu>root-menu</menu -->
    </action>
  </mousebind>
```

It will disable the right-click to shows menu (`startx -- -nocursor` hide mouse cursor not prevent you to right-click open menu).

There are also `openbox/menu.xml` to customize the right-click menu item, e.g.:

```
  <item label="Run Image app">
    <action name="Execute"><execute>/home/m/img</execute></action>
  </item>
```

You can choose right-click menu item `Reconfigure` once `menu.xml` or `rc.xml` edited to take effect.

I also posted answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405618/how-to-change-autologin-from-root-to-non-root-user/406549#406549), to solve auto start issue as non-root.

Comment: I will do what you said soon and say the results, but before that, I have a question: I think the only way I can do what you said above is putting `startx` inside `/etc/rc.local`, and when I do that, my board startups as root user, and because of this, pulseaudio or gtk-based programs will not start for `root` user!

Comment: I think the problem is system autologins as root user and because of that it can't execute my gtk code true! If I could change it to non-root user I think it would be OK?

Comment: @user145959 You can always do `su - m -c "exec /home/m/img"` to run as `m` user. You can also debug your ~/.xinitrc, rc.local by doing something like `echo 5 > /tmp/my.log` to know it's run to the first line, last line, created file with root(`ls -l /tmp/my.log` to know), or even do `env > /tmp/env.log` to know the env is correct to run your img program.

Comment: What about something like `pulseaudio`, I know it doesn't start as root user, how can I fix it? (I ask because some functions in my code need it).

Comment: I think I must use something like this inside `/etc/rc.local` :  `su - m -c startx`. Is this true?

Comment: Also another user here told me to make a systemd unit file: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405618/how-to-change-autologin-from-root-to-non-root-user

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=42888 shows you can do `su -s /bin/bash -c startx m&` . I'm not sure your system has `systemd` or not, you should use `systemd` if exists.

Comment: unfortunately `su -s /bin/bash -c startx m&` doesn't work! If I put `startx` inside `/etc/rc.local` it works but when I add something to it, it doesn't work :(

Comment: About systemd, I did what that user told me in other topic, but it didn't work too!

Comment: @user145959 Is your system has systemd installed before you try this ? Or you perform new install systemd because of this ?

Comment: Really I don't know if my system has `systemd` or not. I only searched the folder `/etc/systemd/system` and found it. then I did create `autologin.service` file inside it! I use Armbian 5.30 that claims is Ubuntu server 16.04(`3.4.113-sun8i #16 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jun 13 14:15:57 CEST 2017 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux`)

Comment: @user145959 What is the output of `systemctl get-default` ?

Comment: `graphical.target`

Comment: @user145959 I posted the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/406549/64403)

Comment: I did change this line ` <decor>yes</decor>` to  `<decor>no</decor>` but I have borders yet!

Comment: @user145959 The bottom part of original files `rc.xml`has been comment out, you need to uncomment all of them. Better backup the file first, then copy my bottom part and replace the part between `</menu>` and `</applications>`. Be careful xml is  sensitive, it will cause entire config file stop working if missing single tag or set the wrong value. And also local rc.xml values will override /etc/'s rc.xml.

Answer (score 1):

With openbox (which is what you're using according to one of the logs) a better option to open a graphical application (after logging in) for a single user would be to use `~/.config/openbox/autostart`.

For all users, try `/etc/xdg/openbox/autostart`.

Source: http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Autostart